# How to change the default branch for a Azure Devops YAML Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've created a YAML pipeline on a branch and tested it from that branch. I subsequently merged it into master and deleted the branch. But the original branch keeps appearing as the default for the pipeline. How can I change the default value to "master"?

There is nothing in the YAML to define the default branch. This appears to be some configuration item in Azure Pipelines.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Go to Pipeline runs and click on Edit

   [image: ![enter image description here]
2. then to `Options -> Triggers`:

   [image]
3. Open `YAML` tab and here you can change default branch:

   [image]

Comment: Great, thanks. You know I think I used to know this, but when I went back to it, I could not remember how to get to that configuration screen. "Triggers" is not the intuitive way :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer....I thought this might be something within the yaml itself but appears its at a level higher than that. :)